how to set gufw/ufw firewall rules?
I want to set up through gufw or through ufw directly from the terminal, the next settings from the first print screen
The second print screen is the one from gufw, if in that gufw window, I must set up these rules.
​It is a must to add these rules in order for an app to work properly.
It seems that for the first rule, the command is:
sudo ufw allow from 141.0.145.180/32 to any port 64297 proto tcp

Unfortunately, for the second rule, it should be something like that, but it doesn't work:
sudo ufw allow 0:64000/tc
ERROR: Bad Port.​

Any ideas, please?
Thank you.



Please edit your previous question rather than posting a duplicate

Thank you for your advice @steeldriver, can you also please, have some advises for my issue, please? Thank you.

See at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04-es

It is a must to add these rules in order for an app to work properly.
It seems that for the first rules the command is:
sudo ufw allow from 141.0.145.180/32 to any port 64297 proto tcp
Unfortunately, for the second rule, it should be something like that, but it doesn't work:
sudo ufw allow 0:64000/tc ERROR: Bad Port.​
Any ideas, please?
Thank you.

This question is similar to: How to add these two rules in gufw/ufw. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for your concerns about similar questions @OrganicMarble. Indeed, the question is similar. I would really appreciate if you would have some advises about my issue, please. Thank you.

You cannot use port 0 in ufw rules. Port 1 is the lowest number allowed. See https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2002778.html
There is also a typo in your command. You left the p out of tcp
So the best you can do if you must specify port numbers is:
$ sudo ufw allow 1:64000/tcp
Rule added
Rule added (v6)

